Can I get a console unicode characters screen width and if they can be overlapped?
I've dug through the properties  of char and I'm not finding a way to see it.  In forms, I'm could measure the font based on type and size, but clearly I can't do that with a console.  I find I'm required to add a space after some Unicode characters because the following text will overlap it if I don't.  Some Unicode characters are twice the width of others.
Example:

Currently, I'm having to eyeball it and create a map stating this information, but would like to make it more generic.
I found this, but that is more for padding over all strings and I'm building a library to generate colors, symbols, and formatting and returning a full string for a user to use Console.WriteLine(fullLineText);
I found out about Variation Selectors, but that is only if I already know which one's need them.  Not much different visually, that just adding the space, like I was before.
Example:
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
//Has '\ufe0f' (Color) Variation Selector
//The '\ude0e' (Monochrome) Variation Selector
Console.WriteLine("v1: [\u2620]\n" +
                  "v2: [\u2620\ufe0f]\n" +
                  "v3: [\u2620 ]");


Is it possible to programmatically figure it out?

Consoles should generally use fixed width fonts. Which should be true, if you stick to the characters that are defined with a fixed width... Can you use control characters to reposition the cursor? Which might be recalculated by the console as a fixed position?

I'm not controlling what is written to screen since this is a library.   This library is using Unicode characters and symbols and passing text with Unicode character within it.   If I could get all Unicode characters and symbols to be the same size that would be great, but how?   Try it yourself...  Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Console.WriteLine("\u2776");
Console.WriteLine("\u278a");
Console.WriteLine("\U0001F435");
Console.WriteLine("\u2776\u278a\U0001F435");

I found some things about Variation Selectors..  But that is only if I already know which one's need it them..

Console.WriteLine("v1: [\u2620]\nv2: [\u2620\ufe0f]");  Not much different visually, that just adding the space, like I was before.

@Chizl "If I could get all Unicode characters and symbols to be the same size that would be great, but how?" - That's entirely up to the terminal-emulator your users are using.

@Dai Since I'm building the string to return to the user, shouldn't I be able to normalize the symbols to match size of my text?

@Chizl I think you misunderstand what a String is...

@Chizl May I ask what you mean by "normalize the symbols"? Unicode normalization has nothing to do with anything visual/aesthetic/on-screen, it's about optimizing how graphemes are represented and ordered in-memory for faster processing and things of that nature.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

From what I can gather, there isn't a real way outside of creating a map for everything.  With Rune, I find most of the 1/2 byte looking characters have Plane set to 0 and BMP is set to True, but that isn't in all cases.
You will notice that \u23f0 has an extra space and \ud83c\udd8f is missing the space.  I guess I'll just map out the ones I'll support and leave it to the user to append a space when they need it.
Examples I used, where it states Padded: True, means I added \ufe0f:

EDIT: List of all emoji characters that have the variation selectors. Color and Monochrome:
https://unicode.org/Public/16.0.0/ucd/emoji/emoji-variation-sequences.txt
